# Export or Forward /var/spool/mail/USER (readable for customer)

Tags: bash, email-server, shell-scripting, email-bounces

there are some bounce mails in the `/var/spool/mail/USER` directory that failed to send. Now the customer receives all of those mails from us because he does not have direct access to them.

I can forward one by one with mutt, but there are so many of them.
Is there any shortcut to ...

- ... send all mails as attachment to the customer?
- ... forward all mails with their attachments in a tricky script?

This does not seem unusual so I hope someone knows the solution.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like:

```
formail -i "To: user@example.com" -s sendmail -t < /var/spool/mail/USER
```

`formail` is usually included with `procmail`. This will add a new To: header while replacing any old To: header with Old-To:. `sendmail -t` is executed for each message found in the standard input.